# pack multiple python tuple and sort

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

Question: You are required to write a program to sort the (name, age, height) tuples by ascending order where name is string, age and height are numbers. The tuples are input by console. The sort criteria is:

1: Sort based on name;
2: Then sort based on age; 
3: Then sort by score. The priority is that name > age > score. If the following tuples are given as input to the program: `Tom,19,80 John,20,90 Jony,17,91 Jony,17,93 Json,21,85` Then, the output of the program should be: `[('John', '20', '90'), ('Jony', '17', '91'), ('Jony', '17', '93'), ('Json', '21', '85'), ('Tom', '19', '80')]`

My code:

```
info = input()
info_list = [(name, age, height) for name, age, height in 
case.split(',') for case in info.split(' ')] 
sorted(info_list, key = lambda name:name[0])
```

The error I got was: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `key` to `sorted` to specify the base of your sort.

```
s = 'Tom,19,80 John,20,90 Jony,17,91 Jony,17,93 Json,21,85'

lst = [tuple(x.split(',')) for x in s.split()]

print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2])))
# [('John', '20', '90'), ('Jony', '17', '91'), ('Jony', '17', '93'), ('Json', '21', '85'), ('Tom', '19', '80')]                                      [Program finished]
```

where `s` is your input string.

Comment: Thanks! This is useful. Can you please tell me conceptually, what's wrong with `info_list = [(name, age, height) for name, age, height in 
case.split(',') for case in info.split(' ')] `?

Comment: Your list comprehension will throw a `NameError`, because when it tries to to split `case`, `case` is not defined. The split by space should happen before split by comma. Keeping that corrected as well, it doesn't work since you are unpacking to three variables in the iteration. Iteration over split will iterate over each split. When I say each split, it means `'Tom'` in one iteration, `19` in the next and so on. It's not that you are getting all the three `'Tom'` , `19` and `80` in a single iteration. Hence the `ValueError`.

Answer (score 3):

The solution would be:

```
info = input()
info_list = [case.split(',') for case in info.split(' ')] 
print(sorted(info_list))
```

Example output:

```
Tom,19,80 John,20,90 Jony,17,91 Jony,17,93 Json,21,85
[['John', '20', '90'], ['Jony', '17', '91'], ['Jony', '17', '93'], ['Json', '21', '85'], ['Tom', '19', '80']]
```

And to explain why your code doesn't work is:

- Using multiple iterators, only works for a sequence of sequences, whereas just one sequence won't work.
- Why doesn't it work with a sequence, it will try to unpack the singular element, i.e `1`, which can't be unpacked as it isn't an iterable with 3 elements, that's the main reason it works for i.e `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: please note that the original question asks tuples within the big list, if so, would your explanation still holds for the mistake I made? Thanks!

Comment: also, when you say multiple iterators, did you mean `name, age, height` in the `[(name, age, height) for name, age, height in case.split(',') for case in info.split(' ')]` part?

Comment: @EdwardLin Yeah